# Cloud foundry: 'Application failed to start' with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, cloud-foundry

I have a simple express app with `mongoose`. When I try to upload it to cloudfoundry using vmc push, the deployment process fails at:

```
Checking savenswap... GAVE UP
Application failed to start.
```

I thing the problem is when I use the line:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

it fails, because when I don't use `mongoose`, but `mongoDB` normally, it succeeds in uploading the app. Do I have to run like a npm install on my `cloudfoundry` instance??

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Foundry should handle the installation of npm modules. Do you have a valid package.json file listing your dependencies? Have you run npm install and shrinkwrap locally?

See http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/12/19/recent-changes-in-node-js-modules-support/ for more on this.

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like you haven't installed mongoose local to the project using 'npm install'